# Enviar datos POST sin formulario

Tags: php

He estado utilizando ajax, todo bien hasta ahí, el problema es que necesito enviar información de varios lados no es un form, quiero generar un reporte en pdf, el prblema es que no se como pasar esa información y que se muestre en una ventana.

```
$.ajax({
        data:{
        "alumno":$().val(),
        "matricula":"#txt_matricula".val(),
        "carrera":"#txt_carrera".val(),
        "grupo":"AE9".val(),
        "celular":"#txt_celular".val(),
        "email":"#txt_email".val(),
        "nivel":"#sel_modulo".val(),
        "pago":"#sel_pago".val(),
        "grupo_ins":"#sel_grupo".val(),
        "horario":"#txt_horasi".val(),
        "docente":"#txt_docasi".val(),
      },
        url:"php/format_f.php",
        type:"POST",
        beforeSend: function(){

        },
          success:function(vista){
            window.location.href = 'php/format_f.php';
            Mensaje("verde","Se ha generado tu inscripción con exito!");
          }
    });
```

El archivo `format_f` es el que resive y muestra la información, pero alguna solución para poder enviarlos, O que otra forma me recomiendan que no sea usando form.

Comment: Si te fijas en la [documentación](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/), las peticiones Ajax pueden ser pasadas con un atributo `data` en el cual irían los datos que quieres pasar al archivo PHP.  Ejemplo: `url:"php/format_f.php",
        type:"POST", data: data,
        beforeSend: function(){` aquí, el último `data` se refiere a la variable donde almacenaste los datos que quieres enviar en tu petición.

Comment: si puedo enviar eso, el problema es que quiero que al enviarlos se habra mi archivo **format_f.php**

Comment: y si guardas los resultados en una variable de [sesión](http://php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.session.php)?